# Upgrading from Jenkins Amazon ECS plugin 1.16 to 1.20 results in need to handle iam:passRole and trust relationship?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecs

Have any other fargate ECS jenkins cluster needed to handle the passRole/trust relationship?   We normally do not pass special roles to our ecs instances and configure a general role as all the instances have identical requirements.

After upgrading jenkins and then upgrading all of its plugins I began to see errors.   **Amazon Elastic Container Service** plugin upgraded from 1.16 to 1.20.   First, I saw errors in the jenkins log about adding **iam:PassRole** missing from my ecs controlling policy.  After adding it I now reach the error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ClientException: ECS was unable to 
assume the role 'arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole' 
that was provided for this task. 
Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust 
relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has 
permissions to pass this role.
```

I will configured the pass role/trust relationship but the fact I need to do so is troubling as we aren't passing a role or at the very least do not intend to do so.  It sure looks like we do not have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  It seems that the upgrade from 1.16 to 1.20 resulted in **taskRole** and **executionRole** for each template set to values in jenkin's config.xml.  I stopped jenkins, manually deleted those keys from each template and started.  Now, jenkins can attempt to launch the container tasks